# Como trocar a cor do body com onclick() a partir de buttons? Javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-eventos

Olá, no seguinte exercício, deve haver 3 buttons, sendo que clickando em cada um, mudará a cor do body pela cor indicada no botão(usando a mesma função para todos), porém minha tentativa foi falha, gostaria de saber porque, segue a baixo o enunciado do exercício e minha tentativa:

1)Os elementos  devem alterar a cor de fundo da página, quando clicados de acordo com a respectiva cor. Apresente o javascript necessaro para que isso funcione.

button id=”azul”>Azul

button id=”verde”>Verde

button id=”vermelho”>Vermelho

html:

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset = "utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href = "./css/style.css">
    <title>Meu Site</title>
</head>

<body>


    <main>

        <button id=”azul” onclick="trocarcor(id)">Azul</button>
        <button id=”verde” onclick="trocarcor(id)">Verde</button>
        <button id=”vermelho” onclick="trocarcor(id)">Vermelho</button>

    </main>

    <script src="./scripts/app.js"></script>
</body>
```

Javacript:

```
function trocarcor(id) {
if (id == "vermelho") {
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.background = "red"
}
else if(id == "azul"){ document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.background = "blue"}
else if(id == "verde"){  document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.background = "green"}

console.log(id)}
```

Comment: O que ele está imprimindo no `console.log` do id?

Comment: está imprimindo as respectivas cores de cada button, fiz para confirmar que o id estava recebendo "vermelho", "verde" e "azul"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que você está usando esse tipo de aspas `”` (conhecida como *aspas inglesas* ou *aspas curvas*) no atributo `id` que não funciona como delimitador: ou usa aspas duplas normal `"` ou simples `'`.

Provavelmente o console.log(id) está exibindo `”azul”` (ou outras cores) e não está satisfazendo nenhum dos `if`'s.

Veja:

```js
function trocarcor(id) {
if (id == "vermelho") {
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.background = "red"
}
else if(id == "azul"){ document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.background = "blue"}
else if(id == "verde"){  document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.background = "green"}

console.log(id)}
```

```html
<main>
   <button id="azul" onclick="trocarcor(id)">Azul</button>
   <button id="verde" onclick="trocarcor(id)">Verde</button>
   <button id="vermelho" onclick="trocarcor(id)">Vermelho</button>
</main>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, era isso!!

Comment: Porém uma dúvida, eu coloquei um console.log(id) dentro da function, e estava retornando "vermelho", "azul" etc, (sem usar o this), não deveria estar funcionando? já que id = "vermelho" ?

Comment: Mas estava alterando a cor do body?

Comment: não, apenas retornava console.log(id)  "vermelho"

Comment: Alterei a resposta. O problema me parece ser nas aspas.

Comment: obrigado, era erro no enunciado da questão então, não tinha notado...

Comment: Pode marcar a resposta com ✔️

Answer (score 1):

Seguindo a resposta do @Sam, você pode otimizar seu código da seguinte forma:

```js
function trocarcor(id) {
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.background = id;
}
```

```html
<main>
   <button id="blue" onclick="trocarcor(this.id)">Azul</button>
   <button id="green" onclick="trocarcor(this.id)">Verde</button>
   <button id="red" onclick="trocarcor(this.id)">Vermelho</button>
</main>
```